# Set fragment ui when actvitivity starts/launches

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a activity embeds a framgment in layout xml using "fragment" tag.
Fragment class has a simple method to set it's TextView on demand like below:

```
MyFragment{
 void setNameText(String user){
   mNameText.setText(user);
 }
}
```

I get fragment reference inside activity oncreate as below:

```
MyActvity::onCreate(){
        myFrag = (MyFrag)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myfrag_id);
}
```

Now i need to set myFrag's name when the activity is launched. I tried calling "myFrag.setNameText(x)" from Activity::onCreate and Actvity::onResume. Both times get null pointer exception insdie "setNameText()" method on "mNameText" object.

```
Error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxxxxxActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

What is the right place to access child fragment's ui object when launching the activity?

Answer (score 0):

When the Activity calls onCreate ，Fragment is not attached to the Activity, you must be in fragment's onCreateView method calls the findViewById to bind your TextView, and then you will can setText